# Restart a bat file every 15 min

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a little bat script that stops working every 20 minutes or so, so I want it to restart every 15 minutes or so. This is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
:A
start start.bat
timeout /t 1200 >null
taskkill /f /im cmd.exe >nul
pause
goto A
```

Obviously this doesnt work as it quits the script that is supposed to restart the script... Any tips for another way of doing this, or a fix for my restart script?

Comment: It would probably just be easier to fix your other script, especially since normal scripts done just "stop working."

Comment: Its a script that connects to steams servers, and every so often steam just ends the connection.. So as a temporary fix i thought id do this so that i get some time to find and fix the issue.. As it is now, i need to manually connect to my azure server which takes like 20min for some reason, then i need to restart it.. Much easier if its automatic.

Comment: You should not name the `.bat` **start** as it is also an external command. Also it is `Nul` not `Null`.

Comment: @Compo `start` is an internal command

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, apologies for the carelessness, apart from that one word my comment remains 100% valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
:A
start "title" start.bat
timeout /t 1200 >nul
taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq title - start.bat" /T
goto A
```

This should work. It sets a title of "title" to start.bat and then uses a filter to find that window and close it. The /T is just for closing the child processes too.

Comment: @MartinTheNob It worked here. Can you explain what didn't work?

Comment: It just opens the "start.bat", then lets it run forever

Comment: @MartinTheNob No, it runs for 20 minutes.

Comment: Now it says "INFO: No running tasks With the specified criteria. Press any key to continiue . . ."

Comment: @MartinTheNob Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: Yeah, i did.. It just wont find the proccess

Comment: @MartinTheNob: check the exact WindowTitle with `tasklist /v |find "title"`

Comment: @MartinTheNob That's weird. When the start.bat file is running, check its title: it should be "title - start.bat". I can't help you more than that, since apparently your cmd isn't the same as my cmd.. You could also try renaming start.bat to something else, because it is known that cmd has problems with such names (names same as its internal commands).

Comment: Yeah, i checked that last time, its the same as you said. I'll try changing it later, but thanks for trying :P

Comment: wow.. i feel so stupid right now.. It worked now for some reason, so thanks i guess :P

Comment: @MartinTheNob Haha, no problem!

Answer (score 2):

Scheduled tasks; run this job every fifteen minutes (yes it's a lot of start at entries) and [X] stop this job if it runs longer than 15 minutes.